# Batch select statements with a case function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select Site, IP from Router where site = '270'
Select Site, IP from Router where site = '271'
Select Site, IP from Router where site = '272'
Select Site, IP from Router where site = '273'
Select Site, IP from Router where site = '274'
...
.....
Select site, IP From Router where site = '300'
```

Normally this would pull back four output rows. However Some of these records don't exist. I have been running IP updates on these sites through a batch update statement. Is there anyway to add a case statement to this to return if a site doesn't exist?

for example:

```
select site,IP from router 
Case = Site 
When site = '270' then site,IP
when site = '270' then site,IP
else 'Null'
end
where site in (270,271,...ect.)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE in this way

```
select 
    case site 
         When site in (270,271,...ect.) then site else 'NULL' end as site, 
    case site 
         When site in (270,271,...ect.) then ip  else 'NULL' end  as ip
from my_table    
where site in (270,271,...ect.)
```

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE site IN ()` will not return anything for sites without records, what you can do is use a left join to your `router` table from a driver table that has a list of the sites you want to include, you can query from a list of values like this:

```
SELECT a.site,b.IP
FROM (VALUES (270), (271), (272), (273), (274), (275), (276)) AS a(sites)
LEFT JOIN router b
  ON a.sites = b.site
ORDER BY a.site,b.IP
```

Alternatively if you have the list of `site` values you want to query in a table already:

```
SELECT a.site,b.IP
FROM sitelist a
LEFT JOIN router b
  ON a.site = b.site
ORDER BY a.site,b.IP
```

This will return at least one record for every `site` in the list/table in addition to all `site`/`ip` combinations where some exist.